# Unexpected 1.0000 top_k_categorical_accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a classification model, and getting some weird metric values. The top1 accuracy is fairly low and has relatively normal behavior, but the top_k_categorical_accuracy (with the default `k=5`) is often exactly 1.0000. This seems highly implausible, given how low the top1 accuracy is. What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the model predicting 0.00000000 for most categories for a given example. Keras uses [`in_top_k`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5912f51d580551e5cee2cfde4cb882594b4d3e60/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L4754) for calculating the `top_k_categorical_accuracy` metric. In the documentation:

> Note that the behavior of `InTopK` differs from the `TopK` op in its handling of ties; if multiple classes have the same prediction value and straddle the top-`k` boundary, all of those classes are considered to be in the top `k`.

So all predictions of 0 are tied, and will count as part of the top "5" as long as 4 or fewer predictions are nonzero. This means that all 200 classes count as the top 5, and thus we get 1.0000 accuracy for this metric.

Relevant GitHub issue: [#10767](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10767)